# How to access ssas cube in excel 2003?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, export-to-excel, cube

Trying to access ssas cube using excel 2003

Data-->Pivot Table-->External Data
But it shows an error ,saying that .It can not query

Also prompting and asking for for the Microsoft office 2003 cd.
Is there any add in to be considered

Answer (score 0):

Run excel using credentials for connecting ssas server as:
`Runas /user:[DOMAIN]\[USERNAME] "[PATH TO EXCEL.EXE]"`.
Then, use 
Data->From Other Source->From Analysis Service and
Provide servername and use windows authentication.